# Dereferencing a pointer into a reference in c++

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

In the following code snippet, are there any caveats that need to be considered?

```
void do_stuff()
{
    std::unique_ptr<my_type> my(new my());

    my_type& mine = *my;

    //use mine 
}
```

It gives me a weird feeling to 'bring out' the value of my by dereferencing the implicit pointer, as it feels like it would create a temporary (but I'm quite sure that's not the case)

Comment: Could you please explain why this is a bad question? (downvoter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is fine with the usual caveats when holding a reference (or pointer) to an object: you have to make sure that the object outlives the uses of the pointer or reference.

In this particular case, make sure that the object inside the `unique_ptr` does not get deleted by a call to `reset()` or `delete my.release();` which I think are the only cases where the lifetime of that reference might outlive the lifetime of the object itself.

Side note: I am assuming that you have a good reason to use dynamic allocation for that object. If you are not sure, consider not using pointers/new in the first place.

I am also assuming that the reference is not there for *performance*, if it is, you might want to consider as access through the reference or the smart pointer will be translated to exactly the same binary.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to show in the snippet, but I want to pass this pointer around, but rather not have every method depend on `std::unique_ptr<x>`. Sometimes I might pass something not encapsulated in a unique_ptr. Is this a fine use case, in your opinion?

Comment: The first question is whether the object outlives this function. If it does not, avoid using dynamically allocated memory in the first place. You can obtain pointers from a local object with the *address-of* operator: `&obj`. If you *have to use dynamic memory, and there is a single *owner* of the object, then `unique_ptr` is fine, and passing either a raw pointer or reference to a function that will not  hold pointers/references for longer than the duration of your function is also fine, you are just adapting the interface, and that is not an issue *if they won't keep references for too long*

Answer (score 0):

Besides not making much sense (at least in the snippet) the code is alright, if there is really nothing between the construction of `my` and the assignment to the reference.

Comment: There's always a trade-off between brevity and expression. I chose to strip most of the specifics from my example. Please read the example in my comment to @DavidRodriguez if you are slightly interested :) Is that a fine 'use case' in *your* opinion?

Comment: @Max that is fine. If your objects hold something on the free store and you hand out references this is fine. But then again just store the object by value in your class and avoid all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the pointer outlives the (use of the) reference.

One simple way to do that is to use **`const`**:

```
void doStuff()
{
    auto const p    = std::unique_ptr<MyType>( new MyType );
    MyType&    m    = *p;

    // use m
}
```

Of course, if there is not any special reason to prefer dynamic allocation (such as size, or special allocator) then just use **automatic allocation** for the `MyType` object, i.e. declare it directly as a local variable without using the word `static`.